# How could I implement a trap to indicate ASP.Net Session expiry

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I need to create a user login/logout/Session expiry tracking page(ASP.Net)..
It is obvious that I can invoke my tracking page when user logs in and logs out.. 
How do I detect session expirey ?

Comment: You can find a demonstration and answer in this article. [Detecting ASP.NET Session Timeouts](http://aspalliance.com/520_Detecting_ASPNET_Session_Timeouts.2)

Comment: What version of IIS? I have done this recently and found that they are all subtly different, requiring a slightly different method for each.

Comment: IIS6 suggetions to implement same in other versions appreciated..
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your most obvious way in a stateful app is to assume that any hit on a non-login page without being logged in implies that the session has expired.

Answer (score 1):

use the Session_End event in Global.asax. Keep in mind this event does not fires when sessions are persisted outside of the process (in SQL for example)